net6 amazon sso users - how to listuser
How to list amazon sso users in net6 service?
Have installed packages
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.CognitoIdentityProvider" Version="3.7.303.10" />
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Core" Version="3.7.303.5" />
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.IdentityManagement" Version="3.7.300.54" />
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Organizations" Version="3.7.302.1" />
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.SecurityToken" Version="3.7.300.65" />
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.SSOAdmin" Version="3.7.302.49" />

Have tried searching ListUsers method in AmazonSSOAdminClient, it seems it's not present there (AmazonSSOClient is not found at all);
Have tried getting users using AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient, am getting iam:ListUsers instead of needed analog of aws  identitystore list-users --identity-store-id ***

have resolved issue using AmazonIdentityStoreClient from AWSSDK.IdentityStore package

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
